# Xslt transformer - Exception handling

Tags: xslt, spring-integration

I am trying to log an xml tranform exception, which gets printed on the console.

Here is my tranformer :

```
 <int-xml:xslt-transformer input-channel="toMarshallerChannel"  
 output-channel="toConsoleOutChannel" 
 xsl-resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/integration/intake/intake-flow/ackTransformer.xsl"  />
```

Like I said, I am able to see exceptions in the console, but they are not getting written into the log file. I came across a post that suggests using error channel of the upstream component, in order to receive xml transform exceptions. But, my upstream components don't have error channels, unlike what's shown in this example.
Post - http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/130523-how-to-catch-and-handle-exceptions-raised-by-a-xslt-transformer-component